# Complete problems for fast-growing hierarchy classes

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, big-picture

I need examples of natural complete problems in classes $\textbf{F}_\alpha$, definition of $\textbf{F}_\alpha$ can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5686). Also in section 6 there are examples for $\omega$, $\omega^\omega$, $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$, $\varepsilon_0$, so I'm interested in examples for the ordinals $\alpha>\varepsilon_0$.